# Laravel Sendgrid SMTP

Tags: laravel, sendgrid, godaddy-api

Hi I am using Laravel as a backend to send out emails.
I managed to do so by following this guide: https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/

This worked well when hosting the project on my local PC however I keep getting a 500 Server Error when the project is hosted on GoDaddy. From Sendgrid I also carried out Sender Authentication but I still get a 500 Server Error.

API Route:

```
Route::get('/mail', 'Auth\v1\AuthController@sendMail');
```

Controller Function Code:

```
public function sendMail(){
        $data = ['message' => 'This is a test!'];
        Mail::to('john@example.com')->send(new TestEmail($data));
        return '200 OK';
    }
```

Test E-Mail Class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class TestEmail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $address = 'janeexampexample@example.com';
        $subject = 'This is a demo!';
        $name = 'Jane Doe';

        return $this->view('emails.test')
                    ->from($address, $name)
                    ->cc($address, $name)
                    ->bcc($address, $name)
                    ->replyTo($address, $name)
                    ->subject($subject)
                    ->with([ 'message' => $this->data['message'] ]);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:
[2019-08-02 11:37:36] production.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net [Connection refused #111] {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net [Connection refused #111] at /home/gthy6yfbfb5j/public_html/iotmarineapi/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:269)
[stacktrace]

Comment: Did you set the correct variables in your .env as described in the guide you posted?

Comment: Hi @BramVerstraten, yes - infact it works when the project is hosted locally. I contacted GoDaddy and the issue seems to be caused since SMTP requests are not allowed from their end unless the server is dedicated or private.

Comment: The reason I asked is because local and production .env are usually different. I guess you are on shared hosting? Looks like you should look for a different mail service then.

Comment: Yes, we were using shared hosting now switched to dedicated to hopefully get this to work... what different mail services would you suggest please?

Comment: We use sparkpost, but it's not free

Comment: What type of driver would it use? For example if we can't use SMTP; perhaps mailgun?

Comment: Sparkpost is supported out of the box by Laravel. It uses the `sparkpost` driver.

Comment: Thanks! Will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround for this was to use the Sendgrid API since SMTP needs to be setup properly in GoDaddy.